# Asp.net MVC model won't bind list property to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to fill a model that has a list property with data, however no matter what I try the list data that I define in the controller will not pass to my view.

I got a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
public class FilmsViewModel
{
    public Films film { get; set; }
    public List<FilmExhibitions> exhibitions { get; set; }

    public FilmsViewModel()
    {
        film = new Films();
        exhibitions = new List<FilmExhibitions>();
    }       
}
```

then a controller that adds some base data to it:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private IItemsRepository repository = new DbItemsRepository();

    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AddItem()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult _AddFilm()
    {
        FilmsViewModel filmsViewModel = new FilmsViewModel();
        filmsViewModel.exhibitions.Add(new FilmExhibitions());
        filmsViewModel.exhibitions.Add(new FilmExhibitions());
        filmsViewModel.exhibitions[0].startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        filmsViewModel.exhibitions[0].endTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        filmsViewModel.exhibitions[1].startTime = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        filmsViewModel.exhibitions[1].endTime = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        return PartialView(new FilmsViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _AddFilm(FilmsViewModel filmViewModel)
    {
        repository.AddItem(filmViewModel.film);

        Items item = repository.GetItemByName(filmViewModel.film.name);


        return View();
    }
```

And finally my view that just doesn't want to accept this data:

```
@using Project_IHFF.Models
@model FilmsViewModel

@Html.ValidationSummary()
@using (Html.BeginForm("_AddFilm"))
{
    <label>Name: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.film.name, new { @class = "form-control"})
    <br />
    <label>Description:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.film.description, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <label>Location: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.film.location, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <label>Price: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.film.price, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <label>Directors:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.film.director, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <label>Actors: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.film.actors, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <label>Capacity: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.film.capacity, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <br />
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.exhibitions.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.exhibitions[i].startTime);
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.exhibitions[i].endTime);
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.exhibitions[i].id);
    }

    <label>First Exhibition</label><br />
    <label>Starting Time:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.exhibitions[0].startTime, new { @class = "form-control" })

    <br />
    <label>Ending Time:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.exhibitions[0].endTime, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="HiddenDiv">
        <label>Second Exhibition (Optional)</label>
        <br />
        <label>Starting Time:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.exhibitions[1].startTime, new { @class = "form-control", id = "HiddenTextBox" })
        <br />
        <label>Ending Time:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.exhibitions[1].endTime, new { @class = "form-control", id = "HiddenTextBox" })
        <br />
    </div>


    <input type="button" id="VisibilityButton" name="show" value="+ Add second exhibition" onclick="showDiv()" class="btn btn-primary" />

    <script>
        function showDiv() {
            document.getElementById('HiddenDiv').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('VisibilityButton').value = "- Remove second exhibition";
            document.getElementById('VisibilityButton').onclick = function () { hideDiv() };
        }

        function hideDiv() {
            document.getElementById('HiddenDiv').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('VisibilityButton').value = "+ Add second exhibition";
            document.getElementById('VisibilityButton').onclick = function () { showDiv() };
        }
    </script>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm completely lost at this point.

Comment: You're returning `PartialView(new FilmsViewModel())` from your `_AddFilm` controller action, you should return `PartialView(filmsViewModel)` instead.

Comment: Ooh wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If ypu expect the value to be populated on AddFilm action, then `return PartialView(filmsViewModel)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `_AddFilm` controller you are returning `PartialView(new FilmsViewModel());` instead of the FilesViewModel which you previously created.

I believe your code should look like this

```
public ActionResult _AddFilm()
{
    FilmsViewModel filmsViewModel = new FilmsViewModel();
    filmsViewModel.exhibitions.Add(new FilmExhibitions());
    filmsViewModel.exhibitions.Add(new FilmExhibitions());
    filmsViewModel.exhibitions[0].startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    filmsViewModel.exhibitions[0].endTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    filmsViewModel.exhibitions[1].startTime = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    filmsViewModel.exhibitions[1].endTime = new DateTime(0001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    return PartialView(filmsViewModel);
}
```